# How to make windows from Windows software appear in PlayOnLinux?

Tags: windows, wine, playonlinux

I successfully installed a Windows package (Origin 9.0) on PlayOnLinux v.4.3.4.

I can almost do anything I am used to, except running tasks that demand new windows be opened. For example, when pressing Ctrl+F for searching, it is expected that a window will rise to add the text for searching, selecting options, etc. The same is true when trying to export the graph. Some windows opened without problems, like when trying to print (Ctrl+P).

Did I miss some libraries to be added to PlayOnLinux?

Thanks in advance.